# "Cannot load VDM IPX/SPX support" when running assembly program

Tags: assembly, windows-xp, x86, masm, ntvdm

When I try to run an x86 assembly language (built using MASM) program on Windows XP, I get the following error in the command prompt:

```
Cannot load VDM IPX/SPX support
```

However, the output of the program is displayed correctly afterwards, and this only occurs the first time an assembly program is run in a console window.  What does this mean, and what can I do?

(Note that I am using a college computer without administrator privileges; my Windows 7 laptop cannot be used because it is a 64-bit system.)

Comment: ipx/spx is a very old network protocol used by Novell Netware.  What is that program trying to do, do you see any indications it would really need ipx?

Comment: The program simply prints `Hello, world!`.  I don't see why it would require IPX/SPX.  I believe that NetWare utilities are installed on the system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this article](http://rumkin.com/reference/problems/csnw.php) the error message is caused by the Netware client's modifications to autoexec.nt.  To get rid of these message the administrator will have to follow the instructions in the aforementioned article.

The message should not have any impact on programs that run locally, and probably not on the rest of the network connectivity.  And they're not related to the program you're trying to run :-)